# Shared Queue in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, queue, boost-thread

I just simply get packets from network, and Enqueue them in one thread and then consume this packets (Dequeue) in an other thread.

So i decide to use boost library to make a shared queue  based on
https://www.quantnet.com/cplusplus-multithreading-boost/

```
template <typename T>
class SynchronisedQueue
{
private:
    std::queue<T> m_queue;  // Use STL queue to store data
    boost::mutex m_mutex;   // The mutex to synchronise on
    boost::condition_variable m_cond;// The condition to wait for

public:

    // Add data to the queue and notify others
    void Enqueue(const T& data)
    {
        // Acquire lock on the queue
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

        // Add the data to the queue
        m_queue.push(data);

        // Notify others that data is ready
        m_cond.notify_one();

    } // Lock is automatically released here

    // Get data from the queue. Wait for data if not available
    T Dequeue()
    {

        // Acquire lock on the queue
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

        // When there is no data, wait till someone fills it.
        // Lock is automatically released in the wait and obtained 
        // again after the wait
        while (m_queue.size()==0) m_cond.wait(lock);

        // Retrieve the data from the queue
        T result=m_queue.front(); m_queue.pop();
        return result;

    } // Lock is automatically released here
};
```

> The problem is , while not getting any data, Dequeue() method
>   blocks my consumer thread, and when i want to terminate consumer
>   thread i can not able to end it or stop it sometimes.

What is the suggested way to end blocking of Dequeue(), so that i can safely terminate the thread that consume packets?
Any ideas suggestions?

PS: The site  https://www.quantnet.com/cplusplus-multithreading-boost/  use "boost::this_thread::interruption_point();"  for stopping consumer thread ... Because of my legacy code structure this is not possible for me...

**Based on Answer I update Shared Queue like this:**

```
#include <queue>
 #include <boost/thread.hpp>  

template <typename T>
class SynchronisedQueue
{
public:

    SynchronisedQueue()
    {
        RequestToEnd = false;  
        EnqueueData = true;
    }
    void Enqueue(const T& data)
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

        if(EnqueueData)
        {
            m_queue.push(data);
            m_cond.notify_one();
        }

    } 


    bool TryDequeue(T& result)
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

        while (m_queue.empty() && (! RequestToEnd)) 
        { 
            m_cond.wait(lock);
        }

        if( RequestToEnd )
        {
             DoEndActions();
             return false;
        }

        result= m_queue.front(); m_queue.pop();

        return true;
    }

    void StopQueue()
    {
        RequestToEnd =  true;
        Enqueue(NULL);        
    }

    int Size()
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        return m_queue.size();

    }

private:

    void DoEndActions()
    {
        EnqueueData = false;

        while (!m_queue.empty())  
        {
            m_queue.pop();
        }
    }



    std::queue<T> m_queue;              // Use STL queue to store data
    boost::mutex m_mutex;               // The mutex to synchronise on
    boost::condition_variable m_cond;            // The condition to wait for

    bool RequestToEnd;
    bool EnqueueData;
};
```

**And Here is my Test Drive:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "SynchronisedQueue.h"

using namespace std;

SynchronisedQueue<int> MyQueue;

void InsertToQueue()
{
    int i= 0;

    while(true)
    {
        MyQueue.Enqueue(++i);
    }

}

void ConsumeFromQueue()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int number;

        cout << "Now try to dequeue" << endl;

        bool success = MyQueue.TryDequeue(number);

        if(success)
        {

            cout << "value is " << number << endl;

        }

        else
        {
            cout << " queue is stopped" << endl;
            break;

        }
    }


    cout << "Que size is : " << MyQueue.Size() <<  endl;
}



int main()
{

    cout << "Test Started" << endl;

    boost::thread startInsertIntoQueue = boost::thread(InsertToQueue);
    boost::thread consumeFromQueue = boost::thread(ConsumeFromQueue);

    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(5)); //After 5 seconds

    MyQueue.StopQueue();

    int endMain;

    cin >> endMain;


    return 0;
}
```

**For now it seems to work...Based on new suggestions:**

i  change Stop Method as:

```
void StopQueue()
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        RequestToEnd =  true;
        m_cond.notify_one();          
    }
```

Comment: On your updated code, you can't pass NULL to a reference parameter.  Your StopQueue() should be { Lock; RequestToEnd = true; SignalCV; }

Comment: I udptate StopQueue code. Check above...Do I understand you correcrly?@stefaanv

Comment: yes, that is the C++ translation of my pseudo-code.

Comment: Note that on linux at least you'll often end the main thread while the mutex is still owned. You need to join() the threads, and preferably stop the enqueue() calls, after calling StopQueue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 easy solutions to let the thread end:

1. send an end message on the queue.
2. add another condition to the condition variable to command to end

   ```
   while(queue.empty() && (! RequestToEnd)) m_cond.wait(lock);
   if (RequestToEnd) { doEndActions(); }
   else { T result=m_queue.front(); m_queue.pop(); return result; }
   ```

Comment: I would go with the end message.  It may well be quickest to purge the queue first, (eg. by sucking all the entries out in a loop, perhaps at a high priority).  A purge would require a 'bool tryPop()' or a bool pop() method that takes a timeout parameter.

Comment: @MartinJames: There are probably even more solutions, but these popped up in my head and I guess there are arguments for both.  Cleaning up is definitely an argument for the end message.

Comment: The cleanest solutions are usually the best.  If there is a solution that means using, instead of changing, the working code of a class that is as inherently prone to disaster as a producer-consumer queue, then go with using <g>

Comment: I update shared queue code based on your feedbacks...I also write test driver to check if it works...Can check it above...For now it seems to work...Multithreading is hard...So let me know if my above implementation may have problems...

Answer (score 2):

First, do you really need to terminate the thread?  If not, don't.

If you do have to, then just queue it a suicide pill.  I usually send a NULL cast to T.  The thread checks T and, if NULL, cleans up, returns and so dies.

Also, you may need to purge the queue first by removing and delete()ing all the items.

Comment: Good point, you either use a temporary thread that runs as needed and dies, or a permanent thread that you can command via thread communication.

Comment: @stefaanv - such operations are usually not frequent.  I would probably just temporarily raise the priority of whatever thread was trying to terminate the target thread.  OK. it's two kernel calls, but if you aren't doing it that often, it's better that fiddling with a completely separate thread.

Comment: I update shared queue code based on your feedbacks...Can check my implementation above...Letme know if you see any potantial problems with above implementation

Comment: Well, with a templated queue like this, an int or a pointer to anything might be supplied by the type.  'number' should really be of type T and, in the thread, after popping it back from the queue into a result variable of whatever class pointer is being used, compare it to NULL.

Comment: Actually, this is getting near to rant moment:)  There doesn't seem to be any easy way, in C++, of restricting templates to pointer types - an insane decision.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that should be considered is not to block infinitely in threads. In other words, add a time out to your blocking calls like so:

```
    bool TryDequeue(T& result, boost::chrono::milliseconds timeout)
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point timeLimit = 
            boost::chrono::system_clock::now() + timeout;

        while (m_queue.empty())
        { 
            if (m_cond.wait_until(lock, timeLimit) == 
                boost::condition_variable::cv_status::timeout)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        result = m_queue.front(); m_queue.pop();

        return true;
    }
```

Then in your thread, just have a variable to indicate if the thread is still running (I took the liberty to make your consumer into a class):

```
class Consumer
{
public:
    boost::shared_ptr<Consumer> createConsumer()
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<Consumer> ret(new Consumer());
        ret->_consumeFromQueue = boost::thread(&Consumer::ConsumeFromQueue, ret.get());
        return ret;
    }
protected:
    Consumer()
    : _threadRunning(true)
    {
    }

    ~Consumer()
    {
        _threadRunning = false;
        _consumeFromQueue.join();
    }

    void ConsumeFromQueue()
    {
        while(_threadRunning == true)
        {
            int number;

            cout << "Now try to dequeue" << endl;

            bool success = MyQueue.TryDequeue(number);

            if(success)
            {

                cout << "value is " << number << endl;

            }

            else
            {
                cout << " queue is stopped" << endl;
                break;

            }
        }


        cout << "Que size is : " << MyQueue.Size() <<  endl;
    }

    bool _threadRunning;
    boost::thread _consumeFromQueue;
}
```

There is no need to hack your queue class just so it can be used in a thread, give it normal interfaces with timeouts, and then use it in the proper way based on the use case.

I give more details on why this is a good pattern to follow for threads here:

http://blog.chrisd.info/how-to-run-threads/

Comment: why not use wait_for instead of wait_until since you just want to give a timeout?